# Google Search results, author/thumbnail etc

Tags: google-search

Sorry I saw this question have been asked before (i searched for similar tags before posting) but none of them answered my question or solved it for me. I'm not a coder at all, and been putting this site together from codes i grab here and there and i'm almost done thanks to you guys!

my page http://jamesngart.com

I'm reading online you can add "authorship" to the page if you have google+? I just signed up for that but the methods i found online doesn't seem to work?

Also I want to add thumbnails next to my search result. I've used various methods to do this. I've added

```
     <PageMap>
<DataObject type="thumbnail">
  <Attribute name="src" value="http://jamesngart.com/img/homepage/Thumb-Imperial-Airship.jpg"/>
  <Attribute name="width" value="100"/>
  <Attribute name="height" value="130"/>
</DataObject>
```

-->

and

```
        <meta name="thumbnail" content="http://jamesngart.com/img/homepage/Thumb-Imperial-Airship.jpg" />
```

and also

```
        <link rel="image_src" href="http://jamesngart.com/img/homepage/Thumb-Imperial-Airship.jpg" />
```

none of these seem to effect anything when i search for my page?

Thank I would really appreciate the help, almost done with the page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i found the answer to my own question, just posting this in case someone is reading. the thumbs and link to profile is disabled now. it still works if you install custom search WITHIN your websie, but does not workf or google search